# How to calculate page load time in Java application

Tags: java, tomcat

My Java application(JSP-servlets) has been deployed on Tomcat on my local machine and i can access the pages like this.
How can i calculate the page load time in local machine ??

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/products.jsp
```

Comment: From the browser or client perspective or from servlet container perspective? You can use filters to estimate it for the former.

Comment: Firebug can show you how long it took to load the page itself. All the subsidiary parts, though they can be figured out, aren't that easy.

Comment: Use firebug on Firefox or equivalent tool on other browsers.  firebug will give you a detailed timeline for every HTTP request/response involved in loading a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This us the output from firebug. Every time you request a page, it displays the Timeline for each page component. You can disable browser cache if you like.

[image]
**onload:** at the last line is what you are seeking for.

The time from the start of the first request until the end of the last request is 1.11 seconds.
The time from the start of the first request until the load event is fired by the page is 1.12 seconds.

The last two entries are for the google analytics tag.

[Firebug Net Panel Timings](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-net-panel-timings/) are explained very well here.

Comment: What is the difference between two ?  1.11s and in brackets 1.12s

Comment: So you mean to say, in this case complete page load time is 1.11 seconds ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to measure load time. The load event may be followed by additional AJAX XML requests. Also note that every time you will load the page you will get different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to measure it from client (browser) perspective, you can use httpwatch

http://www.httpwatch.com/

Comment: I can multiple page loading times in firebug for single request. Which one is the actual page load time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a snapshot of load-time on your browser, you might want to check out [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)